# Functions in matplotlib.pyplot are inaccessible

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, pip, anaconda

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(len(portvalues)),portvalues)
```

After reinstalling matplotlib multiple times, I continue to get the
following error from the above code:

```
AttributeError 
 Traceback (most recent call last)

《ipython-input-387-fee5ae6f6abc》 in 《module》()

1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

----> 2 plt.plot(range(len(portvalues)),portvalues)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

How can I eliminate the error and access the functions in matplotlib.pyplot?  Thank you.

Comment: Anaconda distribution, by default, has `matplotlib`installed. How have you installed it? Try `conda update conda -y`, `conda update --all -y`, and
`conda update matplotlib qt pyqt spyder -y` in a administrator shell. The first updates conda itself, then all available packages and finally a special attention to matplotlib and the packages required to make Spyder IDE work.

Comment: @berna1111 Thank you.  I have done as you suggested, but the issue remains.  However, I discovered that when called in another Jupyter notebook, the plot function does work, so strangely, the problem only appears in one notebook.

Comment: Do you use `plt` to import anything else in the troublesome notebook? It could be that name is being used to import another module, one without a `plot` method.